# Can I split an IEnumerable into two by a boolean criteria without two queries?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Can I split an `IEnumerable<T>` into two `IEnumerable<T>` using LINQ and only a single query/LINQ statement?

I want to avoid iterating through the `IEnumerable<T>` twice.  For example, is it possible to combine the last two statements below so allValues is only traversed once?

```
IEnumerable<MyObj> allValues = ...
List<MyObj> trues = allValues.Where( val => val.SomeProp ).ToList();
List<MyObj> falses = allValues.Where( val => !val.SomeProp ).ToList();
```

Comment: Damn this should be in MoreLinq !

Comment: In C++ and Haskell this function called `partition`, e.g. `(yooks, zooks) = partition (\c -> butterSide c == Up) creatures`

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You can use this:

```
var groups = allValues.GroupBy(val => val.SomeProp);
```

To force immediate evaluation like in your example:

```
var groups = allValues.GroupBy(val => val.SomeProp)
                      .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());
List<MyObj> trues = groups[true];
List<MyObj> falses = groups[false];
```

Comment: elegant!  I can always use groups.ContainsKey() or groups.TryGetValue() to handle case where key is missing.

Comment: This crashes if one key (true or false) is never used. e.g. if SomeProp is always true, groups[false] will crash with Exception "The given key was not present in the dictionary"

Comment: GroupBy use sorting to make groups. I don't know if it's better to stick with scan iterable twice than making a sort of it.

Answer (score 83):

Some people like Dictionaries, but I prefer Lookups due to the behavior when a key is missing.

```cs
IEnumerable<MyObj> allValues = ...
ILookup<bool, MyObj> theLookup = allValues.ToLookup(val => val.SomeProp);

// does not throw when there are not any true elements.
List<MyObj> trues = theLookup[true].ToList();
// does not throw when there are not any false elements.
List<MyObj> falses = theLookup[false].ToList();
```

Unfortunately, this approach enumerates twice - once to create the lookup, then once to create the lists.

If you don't really need lists, you can get this down to a single iteration:

```cs
IEnumerable<MyObj> trues = theLookup[true];
IEnumerable<MyObj> falses = theLookup[false];
```

Comment: +1 for suggesting Lookup and for noticing the potential problem with missing keys when using Dictionary.

Comment: I think IGrouping should be IEnumerable in the second example?  IGrouping doesn't compile and seems to be the result of the GroupBy extension method.  Or perhaps a cast to IGrouping is required?

Answer (score 18):

Copy pasta extension method for your convenience.

```
public static void Fork<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source,
    Func<T, bool> pred,
    out IEnumerable<T> matches,
    out IEnumerable<T> nonMatches)
{
    var groupedByMatching = source.ToLookup(pred);
    matches = groupedByMatching[true];
    nonMatches = groupedByMatching[false];
}
```

Or using tuples in C# 7.0

```
public static (IEnumerable<T> matches, IEnumerable<T> nonMatches) Fork<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source,
    Func<T, bool> pred)
{
    var groupedByMatching = source.ToLookup(pred);
    return (groupedByMatching[true], groupedByMatching[false]);
}

// Ex.
var numbers = new [] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
var (numbersLessThanEqualFour, numbersMoreThanFour) = numbers.Fork(x => x <= 4);
```

Comment: Adding a comment here to say the equivalent in c++ is std::partiton. Might make it easier to locate a C# partition function for others.

Comment: After reading this answer I might add the phrase "Copy Pasta" to my dictionary.

Comment: [Demo in dotnet fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aObEEK)

Answer (score 3):

In all of these answers you lose LINQ's 2nd greatest power (after expressiveness of course); laziness! When we call `ToDictionary()` or `ToLookup()` we are forcing an enumeration.

Let's take a look at the implementation of partition in Haskell, a great lazy functional programming language.

From [Hoogle](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Data-List-NonEmpty.html#v:partition):

```
'partition' p xs = ('filter' p xs, 'filter' (not . p) xs)
```

As you can see it, partition is an expression which returns a tuple of two other expressions. First, where the predicate is applied to the elements and second, where the inverse of the predicate is applied to the elements. Haskell is lazily evaluated implicitly in this case, similar to how LINQ is lazy through its usage of expressions rather than delegates.

So why don't we implement our partition extension method the same way. In LINQ, filter is called `where` so lets use that.

```cs
public static (IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable<T>) Partition<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate) 
        => (source.Where(predicate), source.Where(x => !predicate(x)));
```

One caveat with this is that if you force an evaluation on the matches AND the rest, you will perform a double enumeration. However, don't try to optimise early. With this approach you can express partition in terms of LINQ thereby preserving its beneficial characteristics.

Comment: It's a nice extension method, but feel like it misses the criteria *possible to combine the last two statements below so `allValues` is **only traversed once***

Comment: @KyleMit That is true. Although looking at the original question again I believe given the syntax in the example and how LINQ works, I would say that it is impossible to have a single traversal as you would need some intermediate memorisation. The closest you can get is a full partition function that returns a tuple of `(trues, falses)`.

Answer (score 1):

Modern C# example using just Linq, no custom extension methods:

```
(IEnumerable<MyObj> trues, IEnumerable<MyObj> falses) 
    = ints.Aggregate<MyObj,(IEnumerable<MyObj> trues, IEnumerable<MyObj> falses)>(
        (new List<MyObj>(),new List<MyObj>()), 
        (a, i) => i.SomeProp ? (a.trues.Append(i), a.falses) : (a.trues, a.falses.Append(i))
    );
```

Does this answer the question, yes; is this better or more readable than a foreach, no.

Answer (score 0):

Had some fun coming up with this extension method based on the `ToLookup` suggestion in other answers:

```
public static (IEnumerable<T> XS, IEnumerable<T> YS) Bifurcate<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    var lookup = source.ToLookup(predicate);
    return (lookup[true], lookup[false]);
}
```

The callsite will look like this:

```
var numbers = new []{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
var (evens, odds) = numbers.Bifurcate(n => n % 2 == 0);
```

I think the usability of this is nice which is why I'm posting this answer.

We can go even further:

```
public static (IEnumerable<T> XS, IEnumerable<T> YS, IEnumerable<T> ZS) Trifurcate<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate1, Func<T, bool> predicate2)
{
    var lookup = source.ToLookup(x =>
    {
        if (predicate1(x))
            return 1;

        if (predicate2(x))
            return 2;

        return 3;
    });

    return (lookup[1], lookup[2], lookup[3]);
}
```

The order of predicates matters with this one. If you pass `n => n > 5` and `n => n > 100` in that order for example, the second collection will always be empty.

One might even have an itch to come up with a version of this that would work with a variable number of predicates(I know I did) but as far as I know that's not possible with tuple return values in C#.

Comment: When it comes to partitioning into 3 groups it becomes dangerous because you need to verify mutual exclusivity of all predicates for it to be predictable (i.e. the predicate application is commutative), otherwise predicate order matters.

It would generally be a better solution to nest bifurcates to preserve the boolean attributes of the operation.

Comment: @tvandinther my answer already states that predicate ordering matters right after the code snippet.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I missed that, sorry. However, I do think that it's not a caveat to take lightly. It's one more place for unnecessary difficult bugs to appear.