# IEnumerable<T> GroupBy with Fluent Validation

Tags: c#, linq, generics, ienumerable, fluentvalidation

So the problem I am trying to solve is that I am using a lot of generic classes with `<T>` that need to execute a .NET Async REST call to retrieve an `IEnumerable<T>` list of objects from an API. At runtime things are resolved fine with the T stuff because I have some concrete instances higher up the chain.

I have a worker class:

```
public class Worker<T> where T : class, new()
```

That has a REST client factory:

```
IBatchClientFactory batchClientFactory
```

where in that factory basically creates an instance of this:

```
public class BatchClient<T> where T : class, new()
```

That BatchClient has an important method:

```
public BaseBatchResponse<T> RetrieveManyAsync(int top = 100, int skip = 0)
```

so that the worker class's method does something like:

```
var batchClient = this.batchClientFactory.Create<T>(siteId);
var batchResponse = await batchClient.RetrieveManyAsync(top, skip);
```

Batch Response looks like:

```
public class BaseBatchResponse<T>
{
    public List<T> Value { get; set; }

    public BaseBatchResponse<T> Combine(BaseBatchResponse<T> baseBatchResponse)
    {
        return new BaseBatchResponse<T>
        {
            Value = this.Value.Concat(baseBatchResponse.Value).ToList()
        };
    }
}
```

Now at runtime things are ok because higher up the chain i will instantiate Worker into something like.. `new Worker<Appointment>();` And the T's will all just work perfectly since everything down the chain is just doing generics.

My problem now is that I would like to evaluate my batchResponse and go through the List and run some validation against each element in the list. I saw [this article on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549339/can-i-split-an-ienumerable-into-two-by-a-boolean-criteria-without-two-queries) that seems to let you split a list into 2 lists using GroupBy via a Dictionary where some SomeProp is the thing you're splitting around.. but can you do that GroupBy logic using a method call? And more importantly can I use FluentValidation as that method call? Ideally my code would look like:

```
var groups = allValues.GroupBy(val => validationService.Validate(val)).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());
List<T> valids = groups[true];
List<T> invalids= groups[false];
```

Where the result would be a List of my objects that are valid, and a second List of my objects that are invalid.

Ideally I would then just make a FluentValidation class that binds to my concreate Appointment class and has a rule inside it:

```
this.When(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.Description), () => 
            this.RuleFor(x => x.Description).Length(1, 4000));
```

Which will hook everything together and be used to determine if my object at runtime belongs in the valids or invalids list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure fluent means, there is a approch to achieve that using LINQ:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Investigate.Samples.Linq
{
    class Program
    {
        public class SomeEntity
        {
            public string Description { get; set; }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Mock some entities
            List<SomeEntity> someEntities = new List<SomeEntity>()
            {
                new SomeEntity() { Description = "" },
                new SomeEntity() { Description = "1" },
                new SomeEntity() { Description = "I am good" },
            };

            //Linq: Where to filter out invalids, then category to result with  ToDictionary
            Dictionary<bool, SomeEntity> filteredAndVlidated = someEntities.Where(p => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p.Description)).ToDictionary(p => (p.Description.Length > 1));

            /* Output:
             *  False: new SomeEntity() { Description = "1" }
             *  True: new SomeEntity() { Description = "I am good" }
             * */
        }
    }
}
```

Code segment:

```
Dictionary<bool, SomeEntity> filteredAndVlidated = someEntities.Where(p => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p.Description)).ToDictionary(p => (p.Description.Length > 1));
```