# how to get empty groups, lazily

Tags: c#, linq, grouping, lazy-evaluation, lazy-sequences

I want to group objects by a `boolean` value, and I need to always get two groups (one for `true`, one for `false`), no matter if there are any elements in them.

The usual approach using `GroupBy` does not work, as it will only generate nonempty groups. Take e.g. this code:

```
var list = new List<(string, bool)>();
list.Add(("hello", true));
list.Add(("world", false));
var grouping = list.GroupBy(i => i.Item2);
var allTrue = grouping.Last();
var allFalse = grouping.First();
```

This only works if there is at least one element per `boolean` value. If we remove one of the `Add` lines, or even both, `allTrue` and `allFalse` will not contain the correct groups. If we remove both, we even get a runtime exception trying to call `Last()` ("sequence contains no elements").

**Note:** I want to do this lazily. (Not: Create two empty collections, iterate over the input, fill the collections.)

Comment: Can you use `where`? `var allTrue = list.where(i => i.Item2)`

Comment: Somewhat related: [Can I split an IEnumerable into two by a boolean criteria without two queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549339/can-i-split-an-ienumerable-into-two-by-a-boolean-criteria-without-two-queries)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The .NET platform does not contain a built-in way to produce empty [`IGrouping`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.igrouping-2)s. There is no publicly accessible class that implements this interface, so we will have to create one manually:

```
class EmptyGrouping<TKey, TElement> : IGrouping<TKey, TElement>
{
    public TKey Key { get; }

    public EmptyGrouping(TKey key) => Key = key;

    public IEnumerator<TElement> GetEnumerator()
        => Enumerable.Empty<TElement>().GetEnumerator();

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        => GetEnumerator();
}
```

In order to check if all required groupings are available, we will need a way to compare them based on their `Key`. Below is a simple [`IEqualityComparer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iequalitycomparer-1) implementation for `IGrouping`s:

```
public class GroupingComparerByKey<TKey, TElement>
    : IEqualityComparer<IGrouping<TKey, TElement>>
{
    public bool Equals(IGrouping<TKey, TElement> x, IGrouping<TKey, TElement> y)
        => EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default.Equals(x.Key, y.Key);

    public int GetHashCode(IGrouping<TKey, TElement> obj)
        => obj.Key.GetHashCode();
}
```

With this infrastructure in place, we can now create a lazy LINQ operator that appends missing groupings to enumerables. Lets call it `EnsureContains`:

```
public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TElement>> EnsureContains<TKey, TElement>(
    this IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TElement>> source, params TKey[] keys)
{
    return source
        .Union(keys.Select(key => new EmptyGrouping<TKey, TElement>(key)),
            new GroupingComparerByKey<TKey, TElement>());
}
```

Usage example:

```
var groups = list
    .GroupBy(i => i.Item2)
    .EnsureContains(true, false);
```

**Note:** The enumerable produced by the [`GroupBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby) operator is lazy, so it is evaluated every time is used. Evaluating this operator is relatively expensive, so it is a good idea to avoid evaluating it more than once.

Answer (score 1):

You could ensure you get empty collections when there are no matching objects like this:

```
var list = new List<(string, bool)>();
list.Add(("hello", true));
list.Add(("world", false));
var allTrue = list.Where(x => x.Item2);
var allFalse = list.Where(x => !x.Item2);
```

Comment: Can you give me a reference where it is said that `GroupBy` is eager? Couldn't find it in microsoft docs. If that is true, then my question is lapsed.

Comment: `List` is an implementation of `IEnumerable`, which is an in-memory collection. Are you confusing `IEnumerable` with `IQueryable`? The latter provides lazy operations until materialized using `ToList()` or similar.

Comment: I don't understand what `List` has to do with my question. The goal is to get some lazily evaluable `IEnumerable`s `allTrue` and `allFalse`, and I was assuming `GroupBy` works lazily. Some other SO answers suggest that too (see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10215531/5333340)

Comment: You've explicitly used a List in your question. Sorry for the confusion, yes, GroupBy uses deferred execution, so the results are only parsed when GetEnumerator or foreach is called against the result. In this case it isn't clear what you're doing with the results. The comment about IQueryable was in case you are using LINQ-to-SQL but didn't mention it.

Comment: You should remove this answer, the correct one is below.